# Creating a linq query that queries 2 tables

Tags: linq-to-sql

Im really new at linq queries and im hoping you guys can help me with this query

I have a Product table and a ProductCategory table

The productCategory table is a mapping between the product table and the category table

So i need to get all the products from the Product Table, that has a mapping form a certain category ID in the productCategory Table.. for example all the product from categoryId 5

Im really unsure how the Linq query should go

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as:

```
myContext.Products.Where(p => p.ProductCategory.CategoryID == 5);
```

Comment: I cant do p.ProductCategory.CategoryID, I cant find any of the properties from the productCategory when i do P.ProductCategory.

Comment: Do you have the relationships defined in the database and associations in your DBML diagram?  Also, is the relationship called `ProductCategory` (case sensitive)?

Comment: no they dont have an association, and yes its called ProductCategory